In .Net's Microsoft Identity, why is .AddRoles colored differently?
I know it is a small thing, but I find it curious and bothersome. When configuring the ASP.Net Identity services, my VS 2022 formats the code like this:

I am just using the standard Dark theme with no customization, and I cannot figure out why the AddRoles configuration is colored differnetly than all the others.
Any insights?
Thanks.

Doesn't seem to happen in my Visual Studio.  Could just be an odd bug.  Wonder if reloading will fix it, or unloading/reloading the project.

I tried all of that, but interesting to know that it seems to be my machine specific.
